# How to snap to particular position of LinearSnapHelper in horizontal RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, pagersnaphelper

How can I snap to particular position for LinearSnapHelper() in horizontal RecyclerView? There is a function scrolltoposition for RecyclerView which scroll to that position but did not keep it in center for this snaphelper.

I am looking for something like below image. So when I set to particular position, it will keep it in center. I dont find anything related to select position for [SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper)

i find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988016/how-to-programmatically-snap-to-position-on-recycler-view-with-linearsnaphelper) , but this doesn't help me.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I did some modifications in the original answer & it did work for me. I wanted the same behavior. Can you please try again with the modifications?
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669074/3354265)

Answer (score 5):

> Add this where ever you want to scroll your recycler view

```
 recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)
    recyclerView.post {
        var view = recyclerView.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position);
        if (view == null) {
          // do nothing
        }

        var snapDistance = snapHelper.calculateDistanceToFinalSnap(recyclerView.layoutManager!!, view!!)
        if (snapDistance?.get(0)   != 0 || snapDistance[1] != 0) {
            recyclerView.scrollBy(snapDistance?.get(0)!!, snapDistance?.get(1));
        }
    }
```

> By using this LinearSnap Helper which is attached to your recycler view

```
  var snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

Comment: Note: this is a Kotlin port of [this earlier Java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669074/115145).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you are looking for a way to jump to a position and have that position centered in the `RecyclerView`.

Maybe you have tried `RecyclerView.scrollToPosition()` but that doesn't snap to the view. You may also have tried `RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition()` and that works better but you may want to avoid all the movement if you have a lot of items and are scrolling a long way.

The reason that `scrollToPosition()` doesn't work is that it doesn't trigger the `LinearSnapHelper` which uses a scroll listener to detect when to snap. Since `smoothScrollToPosition()` does trigger the `LinearSnapHelper`, we will use `scrollToPosition()` to get us in the area of the target view then use `smoothScrollToPosition()` to get the view centered as follows:

```
private RecyclerView mRecycler;

private void newScrollTo(final int pos) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = mRecycler.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(pos);
    if (vh != null) {
        // Target view is available, so just scroll to it.
        mRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
    } else {
        // Target view is not available. Scroll to it.
        mRecycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            // From the documentation:
            // This callback will also be called if visible item range changes after a layout
            // calculation. In that case, dx and dy will be 0.This callback will also be called
            // if visible item range changes after a layout calculation. In that case,
            // dx and dy will be 0.
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                mRecycler.removeOnScrollListener(this);
                if (dx == 0) {
                    newScrollTo(pos);
                }
            }
        });
        mRecycler.scrollToPosition(pos);
    }
}
```

**Sample app**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    private final List<String> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
    private final int mItemCount = 2000;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private final LinearSnapHelper mLinearSnapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (int i = 0; i < mItemCount; i++) {
            mItems.add(i + "");
        }

        mRecycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(null);
        adapter.setItems(mItems);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        mLinearSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecycler);
        newScrollTo(1);
//        fireScrollTo();
    }

    private int maxScrolls = mItemCount;

    private void fireScrollTo() {
        if (--maxScrolls > 0) {
            int pos = (int) (Math.random() * mItemCount);
            newScrollTo(pos);
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fireScrollTo();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    private void newScrollTo(final int pos) {
        mRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = mRecycler.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(pos);
        if (vh != null) {
            // Target view is available, so just scroll to it.
            mRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
        } else {
            // Target view is not available. Scroll to it.
            mRecycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                // From the documentation:
                // This callback will also be called if visible item range changes after a layout
                // calculation. In that case, dx and dy will be 0.This callback will also be called
                // if visible item range changes after a layout calculation. In that case,
                // dx and dy will be 0.
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    mRecycler.removeOnScrollListener(this);
                    if (dx == 0) {
                        newScrollTo(pos);
                    }
                }
            });
            mRecycler.scrollToPosition(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="3px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="660px"
        android:paddingEnd="660px"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> mItems;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public @NonNull
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        view.getLayoutParams().width = 220;
        view.getLayoutParams().height = 220;
//        view.setPadding(220 * 3, 0, 220 * 3, 0);
        ((TextView) view).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemViewHolder vh = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        String itemText = mItems.get(position);

        vh.mItemTextView.setText(itemText);
        int bgColor = (position % 2 == 0)
            ? android.R.color.holo_blue_light
            : android.R.color.holo_green_light;
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(
            holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(bgColor));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mItems == null) ? 0 : mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mItemTextView;

        ItemViewHolder(View item) {
            super(item);
            mItemTextView = item.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    private final static int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is almost correct but I face one problem with it. Position is +1. So if I pass 1 in argument for newScrollTo(1) then it will center 3rd position in recyclerview, i.e. index 2 in list and not 1st index. Why?

Comment: @KishanSolanki124 Sounds like a padding issue. Can you position to the center of the 3rd view by sliding it with your finger?

Comment: Yes @Cheticamp I can

Comment: @KishanSolanki124 Sorry, I meant can you position to the center of the first items (at position 0) through touch.

Comment: Through touch, I can. But not with programmatically or by your code.

Comment: @KishanSolanki124 Interesting. I have an demo app that I will post that works OK. I will get that up sometime soon.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciation

Comment: @KishanSolanki124 I just deleted the first line of `newScrollTo()` since it was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal RecyclerView, you should use `PagerSnapHelper()` instead of `LinearSnapHelper()`.

Comment: What does it matter ? How can I snap to any position programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Just did some research and trace the SnapHelper's source code, it turns out the solution could be very simple:

```
class MyPagerSnapHelper: PagerSnapHelper() {

    fun smoothScrollToPosition(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager, position: Int) {
        val smoothScroller = createScroller(layoutManager) ?: return

        smoothScroller.targetPosition = position
        layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
    }
}
```

And then you can pass RecyclerView's LayoutManager and target position here

```
snapHelper.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.layoutManager!!, index)
```